# JS код не срабатывает по событию

Tags: javascript, html

Мне нужно проверять мой toggle (input type="checkbox") на состояние. Если checked, то рядом дописать слово "On", иначе "Off". Я проверяю это дважды: первый раз при загрузке страницы, дальше по клику. Есть такой код:

```
let toggles = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle');

function checkToggle(checkbox) {
  let checkboxContainer = checkbox.closest('.toggle-container');
  let flagMessage = checkboxContainer.querySelector('.flag-message');

  if (checkbox.checked) {
    flagMessage.textContent = "On";
  } else {
    flagMessage.textContent = "Off";
  }
}

toggles.forEach(toggle => toggle.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", checkToggle(toggle)));
toggles.forEach(toggle => toggle.addEventListener("click", checkToggle(toggle)));
```

Первый раз функция по событию "DOMContentLoaded" срабатывает. Второй раз по событию "click" не срабатывает. Где я ошибся?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не назначаете обработчик события, а вызываете функцию прямо там; вторым параметром в `addEventListener` передается `undefined`.

---

```
toggles.forEach(toggle => toggle.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => checkToggle(toggle)));
toggles.forEach(toggle => toggle.addEventListener("click", () => checkToggle(toggle)));
```

---

Ошибка такая же, как и в [JS-код неправильно добавляет классы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1187628/js-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b)

Обратите внимание на знак "галочка" слева от ответов на Ваши вопросы. Этот знак - для Вас.